# Importing large sql file

Tags: ssms, mysql-workbench

So, I have been searching related threads for a while but still couldn't import .sql file that is about 6gb.

Following is a code I've been throwing to a cmd with elevated authority:

```
sqlcmd -S servername -d target_db_name -i sql_file_path -a 32767
```

This code won't do anything, I do not get any response from it, the cmd window sort of freezes for a second or two, and then nothing.

I also tried:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME, DB_NAME()
```

to check whether I specified the right server\instance.

It MSSQLSERVER as an instance name. Should I include it in the code?

```
sqlcmd -S servername\MSSQLSERVER -d target_db_name -i sql_file_path -a 32767
```

However, when I try this code, it would return SQL Server error 87, with log-in time expiration error.

Is there a possible solution for this kind of situation?

p.s. I have also tried opening .sql file with MySQL workbench, but it for some reason it returns [image: WorkBench Error]

Comment: *"the cmd window sort of freezes for a second or two, and then nothing."* So what are you expecting to display while your SQL files runs? You've not shared any details of what is contained in the file, so displaying nothing might be completely expected.

Comment: Also what does SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and MySQL Workbench have in relation here? They are completely different IDE-like GUI tools for completely different database engine products. If you're using SQL Server, as you're question suggests, then using MySQL Workbench makes little sense. SSMS (currently, as SSMS 20 will change this) is only available as a 32bit application, so it would never be able to open a 6GB file.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, when I mean the cmd window freezes, I mean it seems like it is doing something, but it does not actually return anything, and my database is completely empty. I should've mentioned this earlier, I had a colleague working on MySQL workbench, and he said he was able to at least open the .sql file. So I wanted to give it a go. So, would you suggest to go with the MySQL workbench? if the problem is unsolvable with ssms 19?

Comment: Using MySQL Workbench makes no sense of you're using SQL Server; it's for MySQL.